# ECMA only working in edit mode

Tags: javascript

I'm sure I'm missing some file but this script work when page is in edit mode but not when it is in display mode?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/News');

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Posts');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='PublishedDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Geq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='NumComments' /><FieldRef Name='PublishedDate' /><FieldRef Name='SNAP_x0020_Summary' /><FieldRef Name='_x0023_Likes' /></ViewFields></View>");

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        var title = oListItem.get_item('Title');

        $("#pageContent").append(title +"<br/>");
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Is this site using minimal download strategy?

Comment: Well we started with a minimal master page but same MP used on other pages and ECMA is working fine.

Comment: I mean are you specifically using the Minimal Download Strategy feature on the site?

Comment: Sorry.. .No we are not. This is a blog site .. that is the only difference form our other pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);` instead of `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` . This will make sure that sp.js is loaded , if it is not already loaded.